# Sort of Convolution

Tags: sequences-and-series, convolution

I was wondering if the following convolution I am considering already has a name or well-studied.  Thanks for your help.

If the condition of the positive radius of convergence is not enough, then I am sure we can impose further conditions so that the convolution has a positive radius.

[image]

[image]

Comment: In all such problem you just have to calculate the left and right hand side of each identity and see that they are equal. What is $0\star g$ by definition? What is $g\star h$ and $h\star g$ by definition?

Comment: Hmmm.. $\frac{d}{dx}(g \star h) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} kb_kc_kx^{k-1}$ but $(g')\star h = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} (k+1)b_{k+1}c_k x^k$ right?

Comment: @Winther So, $\frac{d}{dx} b_k x^k = k b_k x^k$? not $k b_k x^{k-1}$?

Comment: Thanks for the correction.  I wasn't careful :)

Comment: @Tom No you are absolutely right, this property does not hold unless $c_k = c_{k+1}$, i.e. unless $h \propto h_0$. I just missed the the index shift.

Comment: I added correct versions for the differential and integral operator.